# Enable HTTPS on external tomcat server

Tags: java, ssl, https, keytool, tomcat9

I am trying to enable ssl for external tomcat server(Tomcat 9) and I have generated a self signed certificate(using keytool) just for development purpose and now after configuring the connector in conf/server.xml ,when I try to hit the url https://localhost:8080/ the page doesnot load and I see the following error in logs

```
INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x030x840xb50xe60xd60xc90x060xafs0x920xe40xf8kXH0x910x170xe00x17B0x840xeb0x0eaH0xc50x1370xaf0x1f0xba(0xb1 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:269)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

server.xml file.

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
<!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
     SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
     library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
     AprLifecycleListener.
     Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
     the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
-->

   <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="C:/Users/0025AC744/clientkeystore" 0025AC744keystorePass="123456"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslVerifyClient="optional"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,SSLv2Hello"/>
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
-->
<!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
     This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
     OpenSSL for TLS.
     Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
     configuration is used below.
-->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                     certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
-->

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<!--
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           address="::1"
           port="8009"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->

<!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
     every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
     analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
     on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
     Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
-->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```

Connector that I added in server.xml file

```
      <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       keystoreFile="C:/Users/0025AC744/clientkeystore" 0025AC744keystorePass="123456"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslVerifyClient="optional"
       sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,SSLv2Hello"/>
```

Comment: On port `8080` you have a HTTP connector running, you configured the HTTPS connector on port `8443`.

Comment: That's one thing, which is the obvious problem the other is, why are you registering two connectors for th `8443` port.

Comment: @Akortex I have registered only one connector for HTTPS,all others are commented.Also if you could tell me the changes I need to make in my server.xml file

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz could you please tell me the changes that I need to make in server.xml file

Comment: @Gitesh: to connect to port `8443` you need to use `https://localhost:8443`.

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz I need to redirect the url        http:://localhost:8080 to https.

Comment: @Gitesh: that is a different question. Start by confirming that SSL is working by connecting through HTTPS to port 8443 (`https://localhost:8443`). Then you can easily find the `<security-constraint>` necessary to redirect `http://localhost:8080` to `https://localhost:8443`.